# jQuery tabs header without using jQuery tabs functionality

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a few links in my page.

```
<ul>
<li><a href=#>link1</a></li>
<li><a href=#>link1</a></li>
<li><a href=#>link1</a></li>
<li><a href=#>link1</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to display them like jQuery tabs header. I don't want to use the functionality like loading the tabs in particular div as I need to refresh the page every time.

I want the user to see a page that looks like similar to jQuery tabs.

Comment: CSS is your friend.  Have a look at jQueryUI's CSS, and try to style the UL to look like tabs (or just use the CSS without the JS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this using firebug in jQueryUI site:

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#">link1</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#">link2</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#">link4</a></li>
</ul>
```